# C# adding an array of bytes to a byte list that continues to grow

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist

How do I convert add an array of bytes to a list of bytes? the list grows every time the timer ticks. this is my current code. Visual studio does not like tempBuffer.Add(temp);. It gives me an error.

List tempBuffer = new List();

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int bytestoread = 0;

        timer1.Stop();
        try
        {
            bytestoread = serialPort1.BytesToRead;
        }
        catch(InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Serial connection lost. Exception types:" + ex.ToString());
        }
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            if(bytestoread != 0)
            {
                byte[] temp = new byte[bytestoread];
                serialPort1.Read(temp, 0, bytestoread);
                tempBuffer.Add(temp);
           }
        }
        timer1.Start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved my own problem. I just used tempBuffer.AddRange(temp); and I believe that is adding the array to my list.